# clojure.spec: `alt` vs `or` for sequence spec

Tags: clojure

I'm following clojure.spec's guide (http://clojure.org/guides/spec). I'm confused by the difference between `alt` and `or` for sequence spec.

For me the two following examples work equally well. So what's the difference between the two?

```
; Use `alt`
(s/def ::config (s/* (s/cat :prop string?
                        :val (s/alt :s string? :b boolean?))))
(s/explain ::config ["-server" "foo" "-verbose" true "-user" 13])

; Use `or`
(s/def ::config (s/* (s/cat :prop string?
                        :val (s/or :s string? :b boolean?))))
(s/explain ::config ["-server" "foo" "-verbose" true "-user" 13])
```

Comment: One thing to try: write a spec using `or`, then hand it to `spec/exercise` it will generate/validate 10 examples for you. then switch to `alt` and do the same. I use `spec/exercise` all the time to debug specs it's awesome to compare what I think should validate to the generated output from a buggy spec.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`s/alt` is for concatenating nested regex specs where using `s/or` specifies a nested sequence. In your example it doesn't make a difference since you are not using nested regex specs. Here is an example:

```
(s/def ::number-regex (s/* number?))

(s/def ::or-example (s/cat :nums (s/or :numbers ::number-regex)))

(s/valid? ::or-example [1 2 3])
;;-> false
(s/valid? ::or-example [[1 2 3]])
;;-> true
```

As you can see, `or` specifies a nested sequence in which a new regex context is started, whereas `alt` specifies the opposite:

```
(s/def ::alt-example (s/cat :nums (s/alt :numbers ::number-regex)))

(s/valid? ::alt-example [1 2 3])
;;-> true
(s/valid? ::alt-example [[1 2 3]])
;;-> false
```

Comment: I think the word is "child-sequence", subsequence exactly flips the meaning, if I'm understanding wikipedia correctly. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence

Comment: @event_jr changed it to nested seq

Answer (score 9):

From http://clojure.org/guides/spec, we know

> When regex ops are combined, they describe a single sequence.

that means if you want to valid the nested sequences, you should do like this.

```
(s/def ::config (s/* 
                 (s/cat :prop string?
                        :val (s/spec
                              (s/alt :s string? :b #(instance? Boolean %))))))
```

And then your data looks like this (**Notice** the brackets around)

```
(s/explain ::config ["-server" ["foo"] "-verbose" [true] "-user" [13]])
```

Also, if you do (s/or).

```
(s/def ::config (s/* (s/cat :prop string?
                            :val (s/spec 
                                  (s/or :s string? :b #(instance? Boolean %))))))
```

your data should be the same as the old one (**Notice** there are no brackets around)

```
(s/explain ::config ["-server" "foo" "-verbose" true "-user" 13])
```

---

BTW, for non-nested sequences. there is still a little bit difference between (s/alt ) and (s/or):

```
;;; for (s/or)
(s/def ::name-or-id (s/or :name string?
                           :id int?))
(s/conform ::name-or-id 42) ;;=> [:id 42]

;;; for (s/alt)
(s/def ::name-or-id (s/alt :name string?
                           :id int?))
(s/conform ::name-or-id [42]) ;;=> [:id 42]
```